# Reconstruct list from its PositionIndex

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, associations

Is there a more elegant or shorter way of reconstructing a list from its `PositionIndex`?

The following I regard quite cumbersome:

```
list = {a, b, c, a, c, a};
pi = PositionIndex[list]

Range@Max@Values@pi /. Reverse /@ Flatten[Thread /@ Normal@pi]
% == list

Clear[list, pi]
```

---

```
<|a -> {1, 4, 6}, b -> {2}, c -> {3, 5}|>

{a, b, c, a, c, a}

True
```

Comment: Your approach uses `list`, but if you have access to `list` there is no need to reconstruct it.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code. Mistake on my side, output should be produced purely from `pi` of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want something like your code, I can't come up with anything more elegant than:

```
Lookup[Association[Thread /@ Reverse[Normal[pi], {2}]], Range[Max[pi]]]
```

It avoids `ReplaceAll`, which is a pretty wasteful function.

The following is a very different approach. YMMV if you like it better or not:

```
Module[{result = ConstantArray[0, Max[pi]]},
  KeyValueMap[Function[result[[#2]] = #1], pi];
  result
]
```

Other than that: write a function for it to hide the ugliness!

Comment: Why wasteful? Isn't it strange that `PositionIndex` does not have an inverse built-in function? Or that inverse can be created with combination of two/three other functions. In my code I needed eight other functions to create inverse. You needed seven.

Comment: It took me a while to understand that KeyValueMap[Function[result[[#2]] = #1], pi] does (result[[pi[[#]]]] = Keys[pi][[#]]) & /@ Range[Length[pi]].

Comment: @azerbajdzan If your goal is to just lookup some values from an association or list-of-rules, `ReplaceAll` is just too big a cannon for the job because it acts everywhere in an expression. As a general coding practice, I strongly recommend against using it if simpler tools like `Replace` or `Lookup` suffice.

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way:

```
SparseArray[Splice@*Thread@*Reverse /@ Normal[pi]]
```

or, if you need the result to be a "normal" list:

```
SparseArray[Splice@*Thread@*Reverse /@ Normal[pi]] // Normal
```

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {a, b, c, a, c, a};
pi = PositionIndex[list]
```

---

```
Values@KeySort@AssociationMap[Thread@*Reverse, pi]
```

or

```
Thread /@ Normal@AssociationMap[Reverse, pi] // Flatten // 
  Sort // Values
```

---

> {a, b, c, a, c, a}

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {a, b, c, a, c, a};

pi = PositionIndex[list]

ReplacePart[
 Range @ Length @ list,
 ReplaceAll[(a_ -> b_) :> (List /@ a -> b)] @ Map[Reverse] @ Normal[pi]]
```

> {a, b, c, a, c, a}

**Update 1** as per azerbajdzan's comment

```
ReplacePart[
 Range @ Max @ Values @ pi,
 ReplaceAll[(a_ -> b_) :> (List /@ a -> b)] @ Map[Reverse] @ Normal[pi]]
```

> {a, b, c, a, c, a}

**Update 2**

```
ReplacePart[
 Range @ Max @ Values @ pi,
 KeyMap[Map @ List] @ AssociationMap[Reverse] @ pi]
```

> {a, b, c, a, c, a}

A more complicated list (as suggested in Brett's comment)

```
list = {{a1, a2, a3}, b, c, {a1, a2, a3}, c, {a1, a2, a3}};

pi = PositionIndex[list]
```

> <|{a1, a2, a3} -> {1, 4, 6}, b -> {2}, c -> {3, 5}|>

```
 ReplacePart[
  Range @ Max @ Values @ pi,
  KeyMap[Map @ List] @ AssociationMap[Reverse] @ pi]
```

> {{a1, a2, a3}, b, c, {a1, a2, a3}, c, {a1, a2, a3}}

Comment: The output should be produced only from `pi` not `list`. I made the same mistake in the original code, now it is updated.  Instead of `Range @ Length @ list` we can use for example `Range@Max@Values@pi`.

Comment: I think this is the only answer so far that works for more complicated lists like `list = {{a1, a2, a3}, b, c, {a1, a2, a3}, c, {a1, a2, a3}}`.   (That list was constructed to break approaches that use `Thread`.)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

```
(Sort@KeyValueMap[Splice@Thread[#2 -> #1] &]@pi)[[All,2]]

 (* {a, b, c, a, c, a} *)
```

**Original Answer**

```
Range[Max@pi] /. KeyValueMap[Splice@Thread[#2 -> #1] &]@pi

(* {a, b, c, a, c, a} *)
```